# Need assistance with saving a table

Tags: html-table, html-email

I was asked to create a table for my guild on swtor for guild members armor, and I want to be able to set it up so that it will save.  I tried using the html style e-mail, but it kept coming up blank.

1. Directly updating on the page itself.
2. E-mailing the data to myself.

Comment: in order to have it saved, you need to write some code for it. It would also be nice to tidy up the code, since there are many unclosed tags in that.

Comment: uh...u cant email it to urself using HTML...u will need to use a server side language such as ASP or PHP. I would recommend using PHP's `mail()` function

Comment: @Mike_Matthews_II i would imagine that he has a separate email for formal stuff then uses the yahoo! mail for spam/trash/shareable mail

Comment: I have tried having it sent to email but it just comes up blank and doesn't list any data from the table, I'm not to familiar with other coding... yet I have only taken xhtml, the table is fine, it works, the actual saving or emailing is the part of the code i am having issues with.

Comment: I would love for the submit button to just be able to save the drop down menus after when you click it, but worse case scenario I could get it to save to either a file or be emailed and could load data into a spreadsheet, my class just ended though so i'll check in when I return home,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't do the things you want to in HTML, I recommend visiting these websites for tutorials on PHP, MySQL database and XAMPP web server:

php: http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html

XAMPP: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html

You will be able to save the table in the database and email it with PHP.